# using additional tty sessions battery life draining?

Tags: linux, x11, gnu, archlinux, tty

When I'm working on my laptop I prefer to work in the arch linux console (without Xwindow).
I do this to preserve battery life, since I don't need graphics for my work, it's not a problem.

However sometimes I need to use X to edit a picture for example, but I'd rather not start X in tty1 where I'm working in the console.

So my question is: If I log into tty2 with the same user and start X from there, will my battery life be drained faster rather than if I would start X in tty1 and leave tty2 alone?

If possible I would like an explanation about how this works, also if my question isn't clear I'll try to give a better example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start X from any tty you like, it just starts the X server process running.

The only marginal difference is that you will have an extra tty process running but as it won't be doing anything, the battery usage will be negligible.